# Openstack installation fails to initialize Top-level container

Tags: proxy, openstack, cloud

We are trying to install Openstack per the single installer [guide](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single-installer.guide.html).

Since the server is behind a proxy server, we are running the installer command with http proxy arguments:

```
openstack-install --http-proxy $PROXY_SERVER:$PROXY_PORT --https-proxy $PROXY_SERVER:$PROXY_PORT
```

The installer window shows the error:

> A fatal error has occurred: Top-level container OS did not initialize
>   correctly

The `~/.cloud-install/commands.log` shows a process error thrown for a single_install python script trying to execute a pollinate command:

```
[ERROR: 08-26 17:08:53, single_install.py:326] Container cloud-init      finished   with errors: ['(\'seed_random\', ProcessExecutionError("Unexpected error while running command.\\nCommand: [\'env\', \'http_proxy=http://129.165.60.148:8
0\', \'https_proxy=http://129.165.60.148:80\', \'pollinate\', \'-q\']\\nExit code: 1\\nReason: -\\nStdout: \'\'\\nS
tderr: \'\'",))']
```

The proxy server uses a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Here is the commands.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12201532/

Answer (score 0):

I got passed this error with the pollinate command by modifying ~/.cloud-install/userdata.yaml  There is a line that constructs arguments for the pollinate command including the proxy server.  To this list I added '--insecure' so that when curl is called by the execution of the pollinate command it ignores the proxy server's self signed certificate.

Comment: More specifically, from what I can tell, the single instance installer attaches the bootstrap container and tries to run curl entropy.ubuntu.com

Comment: For the curl command to be successful it needs both the proxy server and the insecure mode flag.

Comment: For now I've passed the insecure option through pollinate, new packages builds should be available in our experimental ppa in the next hour. Please test and report any bugs to our github project page.